# Select a random element from array and check its index

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I have the first part of this problem down, I am able to select a random element from the array like so

```
function setImage()
{

var images = ['anemone.gif', 'ball.gif', 'crab.gif', 'fish2.gif', 'gull.gif',  'jellyfish.gif', 'moon.gif', 'sail.gif', 'shell.gif', 'snail.gif', 'sun.gif', 'sunnies.gif', 'whale.gif'];
var slots = [document.getElementById('slot0'), document.getElementById('slot1'), document.getElementById('slot2')];
document.getElementById('slot0').src = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];
document.getElementById('slot1').src = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];
document.getElementById('slot2').src = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];
alert(images.indexOf(document.getElementById('slot2')));
}
```

However the second line is not giving me the correct index of the element, and I'm not sure how else to find it?

Comment: setting index in `slot2` but alerting content of `slot0` is it right ?

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you're not just setting the random index into a variable and just using that?

```
function setImage()
{
    var images = ['anemone.gif', 'ball.gif', 'crab.gif', 'fish2.gif', 'gull.gif',  'jellyfish.gif', 'moon.gif', 'sail.gif', 'shell.gif', 'snail.gif', 'sun.gif','sunnies.gif', 'whale.gif'];
    var slots = [document.getElementById('slot0'), document.getElementById('slot1'),     document.getElementById('slot2')];

    var rnd0 = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
    var rnd1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
    var rnd2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);

    document.getElementById('slot0').src = images[rnd0];
    document.getElementById('slot1').src = images[rnd1];
    document.getElementById('slot2').src = images[rnd2];
    alert(rnd2);
}
```

If there is you should try alerting the source of the image and make sure that it matches in format to the images array.

If you're still having trouble, set up a jsfiddle with both html and JS so we can see what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById('slot2')` will gove you the node (`img` in this case). So you can't find this in the array containing `src` values.

`document.getElementById('slot2').src` will give you full path (like `http://....../file.ext`), not just file name.

Use [attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.attributes) property.

`document.getElementById('slot2').attributes["src"]`

Answer (score 0):

Don't you mean:

```
alert(images.indexOf(document.getElementById('slot2').src));
```

Comment: there are two other slots (slot0, slot1) which also require the same treatment, the alert code gives me -1 as the index of the element from the array in all three instances.

Comment: You should probably post more code. What is in the array images? If there is NO image element in there with an ID attribute == 'slot0' your not going to find it :)

Comment: Try alert(images.indexOf(document.getElementById('slot2').src));

Comment: Well if you tried it earlier with the id set to 'slot0' it definitely fails :)